# Error when running C# exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, firefox

I am writing a program that interacts with firefox 47.0.1 using selenium webdriver 2.53.1.0. When I build the program in vs2015 I have no build errors, and when I start the windows form application nothing goes wrong.

However, when I go into the obj > Debug folder to get my file exe, and double click the exe, I get this error:

[image]

Any idea this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Try running from bin/Debug/ instead of obj/Debug

Comment: No, still doesn't work